# Access a process instance in jBPM 6 kie workbench programmatically

Tags: eclipse, jbpm

I want to start a process instance in kie workbench using a button in a jsp page. Please help me. I am very new to jBPM. I went to the documentation and couldn't find. I am using Eclipse. Most of the examples are Maven related.

Answer (score 0):

It is supported by the kie workbench. You can use the remote API in your app using REST services. See http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0.1/userguide/jBPMRemoteAPI.html for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Suddenly, my human tasks are not working in my kie workbench. Even though, i started a process, the tasks are not assigned to users. Earlier, this worked perfectly. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Solved the issue. It is due cached data in my profile.